# HTML : Page Preview just before submit

Tags: javascript, html

I want to pop-up as page preview in one button click of my current html page. But i want to use only Body Elements of current page & Header Elements from other resources.

My Question is:

Could it possible to edit the header (< head>) elements OR just use Header (< head>) elements from other resources. if yes, How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is "other resource"? Other page or what?

To get ONLY the head element or body, you can do it like this:

```
    // head of the element
    var headElement = document.head;

    // body
    var bodyElement = document.body;
```

But it only works for current document. I hope I get it right (because I don't really understand what "other resource" mean).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks.                                                                    The other resources means : other page heder OR get header elements from server side. (Except the  current page's header elements).

Comment: Can't you just fetch the whole print preview page with AJAX? You can send the current body element using the code in my answer, and then process it in server, then send it back to the client.